# Error with python / django1.7 (Exception Type: AttributeError)

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Python and Django and emerged me the following error that I can not solve :

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'apellido'
```

(models)

```
class Humano(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def apellido(self):
        return self.apellido
```

(forms)

```
class formulario(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

(views)

```
def comparar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formulario(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            objeto = Humano(

            nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
            apellido = form.cleaned_data['apellido'],

            )


            objeto2 = Humano.objects.all()
            n = objeto2.apellido()        # el error me marca esta linea

            if n == objeto.apellido:
                z = 'los apellidos son iguales'
            else:
                z = 'los apellidos son distintos'

        return render_to_response('index.html', { 'z':z}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = formulario()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The purpose of the view is to compare a apellido received through a form and compare it with other existing in the database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

Since `objeto2` is a queryset, for you to make the comparison,

```
objeto = Humano(
    nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
    apellido = form.cleaned_data['apellido'],
)

objeto_qs = Humano.objects.all()
#Note that you dont need the call here.. Moreover, unless you have created a new manager named `appelidos`, the () call does not work
for n in objeto_qs:
    if n.appellido == objeto.apellido:
        z = 'los apellidos son iguales'
    else:
        z = 'los apellidos son distintos'
```

Another thing is, you are not saving the created object. This means the object is lost once this function executes. You might want to consider using `Humano.objects.create(..)`

---

Finally, you dont have to loop through the objects individually. You can just query the database like this:

```
if Humano.objects.filter(apellido=objeto.apellido).exists():
    z = 'los apellidos son iguales'
else:
    z = 'los apellidos son distintos'
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things here that could be changed.

The first is the actual error where `objeto2 = Humano.objects.all()` is returning a queryset and as such it isn't returning a single model

Without knowing spanish, I'm assuming you're trying to figure out if any of the other objects in the database have the same `apellido`. To do this you can use `filter` with `exists` which will tell you if any exist or not.

```
any_apellido_exist = Humano.objects.filter(apellido=form.cleaned_data['apellido']).exists()
```

Second, your whole form is duplicating fields and will make it hard to maintain, you might want to consider using a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

```
class formulario(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
         model = Humano
```